# Local Azure Storage Accounts - Where to find the connection string

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-storage-emulator

I am playing with an Azure Web Job project in Visual Studio (C#) that is triggered from messages added to a storage account queue.

At present I cannot find a way to determine the connection string of my local queues.

[image]

When I select my local storage account I don't see any properties

However, when I select an Azure hosted storage account I get a lot more properties, including a connection string:

[image]

For the job to work I need to provide these app config values:
[image]

The Azure Storage Account emulator is running on my machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` as the value of connectionString.

And remember to update your `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs` package to latest version(>=v2.0.0) or the emulator connection string can't be recognized.

Comment: Thank you Jerry! I found this to be very badly documented on the web. It works now after upgrading and setting the connectionString values to UseDevelopmentStorage=true.

Comment: You are welcome. And the document is here in [storage part](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=%2fazure%2fstorage%2fblobs%2ftoc.json#authenticating-requests-against-the-storage-emulator).